# What are the missing numbers in the circle?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Given the following diagram, what are the missing two numbers in the last figure?

[This is from a mathematics book for primary school](https://www.westermann.de/artikel/978-3-14-122304-0/Mathematikus-Allgemeine-Ausgabe-2007-Schuelerbuch-4)

[image]

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 2):

In each given circle, the middle number equals

> (A - B) * (C / D)

where

> all four outer numbers A B C D are from 1 to 9 inclusive, and A and B are adjacent.

The last circle fits this pattern if

> the right number is 9 and the bottom number is 1.

Comment: Why not 1 and 1? Wouldn't this also work?

Comment: @hexomino rot13(Lrf, jul abg? Jryy, lbh pbhyq nqq gur nqqvgvbany erfgevpgvba gung N unf gb or ynetre bg rdhny gb P.)